# Signs in relative vector addition

Tags: special-relativity, vectors, velocity, inertial-frames, relative-motion

So I know the formula for relative vector addition is 
$$w = \frac{v-u}{1-\frac{uv}{c^2}}.$$

1. How do I chose when to use this formula or its inverse transformation for solving vector addition problems in special relativity.
2. In which direction/scenario is the sign of u negative?

Comment: Gallie  $v_{3}=v_{1}+v_{2}$ SRT sign with Lorentz transformation  $\Lambda _{3}=\Lambda _{2}\Lambda _{1}$

Answer (score 2):

When I was studying for the PGRE I came up with my own way of writing the relativistic velocity addition law. I'm sure I'm not the only/first person to think of it this way, but I found it to be quite useful.

---

The way I do it is to **first** not assume any sign dependence. In which case it looks like this

$$
v_{ac} = \frac{v_{ab} + v_{bc}}{1+ \frac{v_{ab}v_{bc}}{c^2}}.
$$

where $v_{ij}$ is "the velocity of $i$ with respect to observer $j$". **Then** draw your coordinate system and account for signs accordingly.

---

When writing it this way it is purely just regular vector addition, and is no different than Galilean velocity addition.

Comment: I thing the equation is also correct if v is a vector